# Job taking forever to cancel

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have had this issue two times these days when I try to cancel a Dataflow job : it is taking forever to cancel.
last thursday it took almost 9 hours to cancel and now another job is stuck for 2 minutes.
Is it not possible to kill a job directly ?
What can explain such a behaviour ?

Comment: That is not expected behavior. Do you have job IDs you can share?

Comment: Hello, thanks it is at 5H now 2016-12-15_07_19_16-6412970468621872432

Comment: Thanks -- investigating.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new issue having to do with the size of the job and ensuring clean shutdown.  We're investigating a few approaches to make shutdown faster.